# Confirmation for a limit DNE proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Given
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-6y^2}{|x|+3|y|},
$$
I claim that the limit
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)
$$
does not exist.

I show this by approaching the point $(0,0)$ along the line $y=x$ (gives a limit of $0$) and the curve $y=x^2$ (gives a limit of $1/4$). Since the limit of a function must be unique, this limit does not exist.

Is my reasoning correct here? My doubt comes from the plot of $f(x,y)$. Visually, it looks as if the $f$ does indeed approach a value $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ (there exists a cusp at that point?).

As a follow-up question, how reliable are these computer-generated plots, anyways? When can we use them? In the case of limits/continuity/differentiability, I feel that looking at the plots of functions usually throws me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made some mistake in finding the limit along $y=x^{2}$. the given limit exists and it is $0$.

Note that $0\leq \frac {x^{2}}{|x|+3|y|} \leq \frac {x^{2}}{|x|}\to 0$

and $0\leq \frac {6y^{2}}{|x|+3|y|} \leq \frac {6y^{2}}{3|y|}\to 0$. Take the difference of these two limits.

Comment: Thanks for the point-out, I had mistakenly written the $|x|$ in the denominator as $|x^2|$.